# Lenovo V570 RAM Upgrade

Tags: memory

Currently, I have 5.7 GB of memory (RAM) on my Lenovo V570 laptop running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I popped the hood and I see and a 4 GB and a 2 GB chip.

[image: A 2 GB RAM in the front and 4 GB RAM in the back]

I did some research and found out there I might have some options to chose from.

1. Corsair CMSO8GX3M1A1333C9 8GB 1X8GB DDR3-1333MHZ CL9-9-9-24 204PIN SODIMM Memory Kit ([source](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-C-E-K-M-N-and-V-Series/V570-upgrade-to-16gb-of-ram-successful/td-p/696025)).
2. Crucial RAM options ([source](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Lenovo/ideapad-v570))

Based on the claims made in the Lenovo forums [post](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-C-E-K-M-N-and-V-Series/V570-upgrade-to-16gb-of-ram-successful/td-p/696025), I am assuming that I can install 16 GB of max RAM on my laptop.

My Board:

```
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 16 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 4
```

4 GB RAM

```
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0034
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: 005001BA
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: M471B5273CH0-CH9  
    Rank: Unknown
```

2 GB RAM

```
Handle 0x0039, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0034
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 2048 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: ***** censored ***
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: M471B5773CHS-CH9  
    Rank: Unknown
```

**My question is:**

What is the difference between DDR3 PC3-12800 and DDR3 PC3-14900? And most importantly, how do I find which one to use for my laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **PCx-xxxxx** stand for:

- **PC3** (*DDR3*) --> RAM Type
- **xxxxx** --> BUS max transmission data rate (per channel)

Answering your question, the ***PC3-12800*** has a max trans. rate of **12,8GB/s**, on the other hand, the ***PC3-14900*** has a transmission rate of **14,9GB/s**

With that being said, it goes down only on your choice/budget and on your need.

If you're planning to use virtualization software, light gaming or more generally "RAM-eater" software (i.e. Audio/Video/Photo Editing...), I will go for the PC-14900, BUT if you're going to upgrade your ram because you're going short on the number of programs you can open at the same time, take this a personal thought, I will go with the PC-12800 one...

Hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: Thanks! I am considering Crucial http://a.co/hFJTa4A OR 2x Corsair http://a.co/8EJohgW. Any recommendations?

Comment: Personally, I would choose the Crucial 2x8 kit over the Corsair one. You can also have a look at this pair of Corsair Vengeance, higher bus rate (12800 over the crucial’s 10600), higer frequency (corsair 1600 - crucial 1333), and lower price (as per now: corsair 129 - crucial 146) ;) https://www.amazon.com/CORSAIR-Vengeance-204-Pin-SO-DIMM-CMSX16GX3M2A1600C10/dp/B0076W9Q5A/ref=mp_s_a_1_9?ie=UTF8&qid=1532066289&sr=8-9&pi=AC_SX236_SY340_QL65&keywords=sodimm+ddr3+8gb&dpPl=1&dpID=51%2BEHiBPGzL&ref=plSrch

Comment: Thanks, but that one is 1,600 MHz whereas my board might need 1333 MHz, 1333 MT/s. ;-) I am going for Crucial as I have heard that Crucial produces their own chip so I am guessing they'd have better quality control. Currently for both my memories Speed is 1333 MT/s, as you can see. I am not sure if my Lenovo Emerald Lake FAB1 board allows higher frequency. Please let me know if you find any evidence that it does.

Comment: Okay, @EdwardKirk, the 1600 MHz RAM you suggested, is supported by Core-i5-2410M, and even if I upgraded my processor to  Core-i7-2820QM.

Comment: Good to know! Just keep in mind your motherboard; if it doesn’t support 1600 MHz RAM, they would “down-work” to the highest possible Frequency your mobo supports (i.e: 1333) and at this point i don’t think it would worth to buy a better RAM and then to cut out part of their capability :)

Comment: You are right, I am going with Crucial [a0.co/hFJTa4A](http://a.co/hFJTa4A) just to be safe.

Comment: Installation successful! No fuss. I am running Linux, so need to increase swap file size - but it is an optional step.

Comment: Happy to hear that! :) Btw, with 16GB of RAM, i would suggest you to set it to the same amount of your memory (16GB), not twice. 'Cause, as per my personal thought, it would be a waste of hard drive space... Not to mention that a system that is swapping a lot, is a not-so-stable one.. Clearly you can choose the config that really fits your need, that's just a personal advice :) If i can ask, what distro are you using?

Comment: I agree. When I installed Linux with 6 GB RAM, the default swap-file was just 2097148 - and I wanna stick to that, at least never exceeding to 1/4 of my new RAM size. I've upgraded to 250 GB SSD, so storage is precious until I get an [HDD caddy](http://a.co/ioKYbiC) - I don't wanna waste 16GB, I'd never use. **_RE Distro:_** I switch b/w Linux & Unix (FreeBSD), for the [community](https://sites.google.com/view/fossusersgroup/home) ([fb](https://www.facebook.com/foss.ug/)), I run. Regardless, I use MATE Desktop. Currently, I'm rocking [Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS](https://ubuntu-mate.org/).